# Handling invalid inputs in Java

Tags: java, oop

I have a class called `Line` and I want to add a method that calculates the line's tangent.
To calculate the tangent I need two points: (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) so their tangent will be (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1). Suppose I have two points and I want to calculate the tangent, there are certain situation that the tangent is not defined (x2 = x1), the line is parallel to the the y - axis ). I want to be able to use this function and when it gets a line that has no tangent, the program won't crash and just show an error.
How do I do it?

This is the function (it is in a class called `Line`):

```
double getTangent() {
    // defined only if the line is not perpendicular to the horizontal axis.
    return (this.end.getY() - this.start.getY()) / (this.end.getX() - this.start.getX());
}
```

Comment: `if (this.end.getX() == this.start.getX())` Or am I missing something?

Comment: But what would the function return if that happens?

Comment: First of all, I think you mean that you want to calculate the ___slope___ of a straight line and not a tangent, according to the formula `(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`. The slope of a line parallel to the X-axis is 0 (zero), so just return 0. Or am I still missing something?

Comment: notice that when x1 = x2 then you divide by zero, that can not happen. Also, in the case of lines, tangent and slopes are the same, but you right, I should change it to slope.

Comment: When `x1 == x2` you don't have an "error" per se, it's just the slope is _undefined_ (i.e. a vertical line). I suppose you could return `NaN` or `POSITIVE_INFINITY` in such cases.

Comment: @Slaw or a horizontal line :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea A horizontal line has a slope of `0` (not undefined) and would have `y1 == y2`.

Comment: @TairGalili we need more code. Are you building the line with 2 points in the constructor? If you do, I think you should handle the case where the points are equal in the constructor, as a line of 2 identical points is not a line. This eliminates your problem, as the points will have 2 diferent coordonates on Ox axis and won't run into division by 0 problem.

Comment: I am bulding the line with two points, but you also have to handle the case that there is an **actual** line for example (1,2) , (1,5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this acceptable?

```java
double getTangent() {
    if (this.end.getY() == this.start.getY()) {
        return 0;  // line is parallel to x-axis
    }
    else if (this.end.getX() == this.start.getX()) {
        return Double.NaN; // line is parallel to y-axis, i.e. undefined
    }
    else {
        return (this.end.getY() - this.start.getY()) / (this.end.getX() - this.start.getX());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use +Infinity for equal `x` if you want to go that way.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that there Nan and +Infinity exits.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea accrding to the literature, the slope of a line parallel to the y-axis, i.e. a "vertical" line, is referred to as "undefined". So how would that translate to java? Should it be [Double.NaN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) or [Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY) or perhaps something else?

Comment: I thinks it should be Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY beacuse of the math behind it - when the angle of the line with the x - axis is getting bigger the expression (x1-x2) aproaches infinty, so unforamlly the slope is of the form "1/infinity"